# how to import django variable to html?

Tags: python, html, django, serial-port

I have to send data from the rs232 port and display it in a graph, use java script
https://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-dynamic-chart/

I need help importing the views.py variable in my html

```
views.py
import io
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from random import sample

    def about(read):
        import serial, time
        arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200)
        time.sleep(2)
        read = arduino.readline()
        arduino.close()
        read = int(read)
        return HttpResponse(str(read), '')
```

**Html**

```
var updateChart = function (count) {
    count = count || 1;
    for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
<!-- this is where I try to read the variable -->
        yVal = href="{% 'about' %}"
        dps.push({
            x: xVal,
            y: yVal
        });
        xVal++;
    }
```

Comment: Define URL pattern, map this URL pattern to the view, render the HTML template in this view. Before that you have to decide whether your "value" is supposed to be an URL mapped to the view (because you're assigning/comparing it to `href`) or the result of computations within the view. And there is actually zero HTML in your question - it's JS.

Answer (score 0):

write this on your views and point a url to it

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def indexw(request):
    context_variable = ''
    context = {"context_variable": context_variable}
    return render(request,'index.html', context)
```